# CSS/Javascript - using hover to show dropdown div

Tags: javascript, css

I am having a hard time of this... I have an existing navigation bar that uses a table (i know it would be better to use a UL tag but i'm editing a pre existing page so would rather not reinvent the wheel). I have a javascript snipped that shows a dropdown menu when you hover. However, i'm at a loss to figure out how in the world to make it disappear at the right time. As in... when you hover over anavbar1, the div is shown as expected. but then, how to make it hide after say a certain number of seconds, or as soon as another navbar dropdown is triggered (like a normal dropdown)? here is my entire code :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:600" rel="stylesheet"> 
<style type="text/css">
    #anavbar0 {
        display: block;
        width: 633px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice0.png") no-repeat 0 0;  
    }
    #anavbar0:hover {}
    #anavbar0 span {
        display: none;
    }

    .anavbar1 {
        display: block;
        width: 104px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice1.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    .anavbar1:hover .dropdown1 {
        display: block;
    }
    .anavbar1:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    .anavbar1 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar2 {
        display: block;
        width: 169px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice2.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar2:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar2 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar3 {
        display: block;
        width: 134px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice3.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar3:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar3 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar4 {
        display: block;
        width: 102px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice4.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar4:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar4 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar5 {
        display: block;
        width: 103px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice5.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar5:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar5 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar6 {
        display: block;
        width: 144px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice6.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar6:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar6 span {
        display: none;
    }

    #anavbar7 {
        display: block;
        width: 111px; height: 107px;
        background: url("../GFX/slice7.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    }
    #anavbar7:hover {
        background-position: 0 -107px;
    }
    #anavbar7 span {
        display: none;
    }

    .dropdown1 {
        display:none;
       position: absolute;
       top:200px;
       background-color: #f9f9f9;
       min-width: 160px;
       box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
       z-index: 1;
    }

    #drop1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 119px;
        height: 117px;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 634px;
        top: 115px;
        visibility: hidden;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    .hoverTable{
        width:100%; border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .hoverTable td{
        padding:7px;
        border:#888888 1px solid;
    }
    .hoverTable tr{
        background: #444444;
        color:#EEE;
    }  
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
        background-color:#294E7A
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    div = {show: function(elem) {document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'visible';},
    hide: function(elem) {document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'hidden';}}
</script>
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr>
        <td width="98"><a id="anavbar0" ></a></td>
        <td onMouseOver="div.show('drop1')"  width="98" class="anavbar1"><a id="anavbar1" href="home.php" ></a></td>
        <td width="117"><a id="anavbar2" href="link1.php"></a></td>
        <td width="115"><a id="anavbar3" href="link2.php"></a></td>
        <td width="134"><a id="anavbar4" href="link3.php"></a></td>
        <td width="78"><a id="anavbar5" href="link4.php"></a></td>
        <td width="117"><a id="anavbar6" href="link5.php"></a></td>
        <td width="117"><a id="anavbar7" href="link6.php"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="drop1" >
    <table align="right" class="hoverTable">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Text 1A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Text 2A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Text 3A</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a plunker with what you have. I will help you, this is a easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move `<div id="drop1">` into td with onmouseover than technically that div will be inside td and so onmouseout event will fire when mouse leaves table cell and "drop1" div.

But if you need to style drop1 you should take into account that top margin will break continuity of td and onmouseout event will fire when arrow touches margin.

Here is (rather rough) jsfiddle to demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/uxnu65wf/

P.S. with this approach you may not need javascript as the same can be achieved by using `:hover` in css.

Comment: thanks a lot, that was perfect. I didn't realize the div onmouseout would be fired by the combined area of the two elements. I learned something new today. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You see how this is 'mouseover'

```
<td onMouseOver="div.show('drop1')" ...
```

You need to add 'mouseout'

```
<td onMouseOut="div.hide('drop1')" ...
```

Which is in the js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
div = {show: function(elem) {document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'visible';},
       hide: function(elem) {document.getElementById(elem).style.visibility = 'hidden';}}
</script>
```

Comment: not quite, i had that in there before, but all it does is hide the div the second the mouse leaves the td element, and before the user has a chance to click on anything in the div that's been shown. since the triggering td has the mouseout event, the simple action of moving the mouse from the trigger area to the dropdown makes the dropdown hide.

Comment: Plz create a jsfiddle and link to it.